# Can Sorcerers convert two units from the same Tribe in one turn?

Tags: small-world

A Cunning Rules Lawyer pointed out that, while the rules for Sorcerers say:

> Once per turn per opponent, your Sorcerers
>   can conquer a Region by substituting one of
>   your opponent's Active tokens with one of
>   your own taken from the storage tray.

It isn't 100% clear if, when you're playing a four player game, you can convert four regions of the same opponent, or if "once per opponent" means you have to target a different opponent each time.

**Does once per turn per opponent mean that you have to target a different opponent each time, or just that you have as many conversions as opponents?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like this is clarified by Antoine from Days of Wonder in [this thread](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/3230688#3230688).  You may only use it once against a given opponent in a turn.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can only use it against each opponent once on any given turn.

They may as well try to argue that there are 3 turns left in the game, and 3 opponents, so they can use it 9 times this turn against a single opponent. That has as much grammatical sense as what they're arguing, and is clearly not what the grammatical structure means.

Comment: No, that would be a fundamental difference in power level.
The difference between "Power bounded by adjacent opponents" vs "Power bounded by number of opponents" is a lot more subtle.